# Xamarin.Android Custom Component Click event binding using xaml

Tags: xamarin.android, event-handling, custom-controls

I am creating a custom button component which involves an label and button. I can set the displaytext and other properties using XAML after defining them in the attrs.xml (like

```
<UButton displayText="Hello" ... />
```

). but i need to allow the Click event of this control to be handled by the user by defining it in the XAML like

```
    mclick="button_click"
```

. but i am not able to find a documentation for handling this. Can you please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look [`Button`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)'s source code.

In this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml?av=f) (Android `attrs.xml` source code), search `onClick`, you will find:

```
<!-- Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is
     clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes
     exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify
     <code>android:onClick="sayHello"</code>, you must declare a
     <code>public void sayHello(View v)</code> method of your context
     (typically, your Activity). -->
<attr name="onClick" format="string" />
```

That why when you use :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

it will find the `onClick` method.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/View.java?av=f#3789), you will see how Android handle the  `android:onClick="onClick"`, in it's `View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)` method, `android:onClick="onClick"` is correspond to `R.styleable.View_onClick`:

```
 case R.styleable.View_onClick:
            if (context.isRestricted()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("The android:onClick attribute cannot "
                        + "be used within a restricted context");
            }

            final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
            if (handlerName != null) {
                setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    private Method mHandler;

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mHandler == null) {
                            try {
                                mHandler = getContext().getClass().getMethod(handlerName,
                                        View.class);
                            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                                int id = getId();
                                String idText = id == NO_ID ? "" : " with id '"
                                        + getContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                                            id) + "'";
                                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find a method " +
                                        handlerName + "(View) in the activity "
                                        + getContext().getClass() + " for onClick handler"
                                        + " on view " + View.this.getClass() + idText, e);
                            }
                        }

                        try {
                            mHandler.invoke(getContext(), View.this);
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute non "
                                    + "public method of the activity", e);
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute "
                                    + "method of the activity", e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
```

You will find, it find the method by reflection.

So, I guess you have forgot to handle the `mclick="button_click"`. As usually, we don't use this to add click listener, it is a little complex. We use `View`'s [setOnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)).